# How to find number in a df column with a mixture of data using regex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

do you know how to transform this code in order to obtain a faster one?
In this code I would like to take only number (decimal or integer) and reject the words present in the column. in fact, in column a I may found both number and words. Thanks!

```
 a=['a', '9','4.5','nnn', '3.4543', '2'] c=[1,10,5,4,4,7] 

df=pd.DataFrame(a,c) 
b =pd.Series(np.zeros(len(df)), name='b', index=df.index)    
    i = 0
for row in df.a:  
    if re.findall(r'(\d+[.]\d+)', str(row)):
        b.loc[i] = re.search(r'(\d+[.]\d+)', str(row)).group()
        
    elif re.findall(r'(\b\d+\b)', str(row)):  
        b.loc[i] = re.search(r'(\b\d+\b)', str(row)).group()

    else: 
        b.loc[i] = '9999'
    
    i = i + 1

for i in range(len(b)):
    b.loc[i]=float(b.loc[i])
    
df.a = b
```

I would like to obtain a=[9999, 9, 4.5,9999,3.4543, 2]

Comment: if you show a sample of your data with your intended output we can help with a solution.

Comment: like this:      a=['a', '9','4.5','nnn', '3.4543', '2']
c=[1,10,5,4,4,7]
df=pd.DataFrame(a,c)  I would like to obtain a=[9999, 9, 4.5,9999,3.4543, 2]

Comment: please add it to your main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply and assign function to create a new column:

import re

```
regnumber = re.compile(r'\d+(?:,\d*)?')

a=['a', '9','4.5','nnn', '3.4543', '2'] 
c=[1,10,5,4,4,7] 

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'c':c}) 

df = df.assign(
    a = lambda x: x['a'].apply(lambda s: s if regnumber.match(s) else 9999)
)
print(df)

      a   c

   9999   1
      9  10 
    4.5   5
   9999   4
 3.4543   4
      2   7
```